# Creating an Excel Expense Tracker

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a simple excel spreadsheet using if/then coding to speed up the process of turning in my monthly expenses.

In Excel, columns A-D are data points; Date, Description, Expense, Notes.  I'm looking to write an if/then statement whereas if I enter "1" for "marketing" in E1, then the value from C1 is placed in M1 so I can then calculate a total for column M.  Furthermore, if E1=2, then copy C1 to N1.

Thank you in advance for your help.
James

Comment: Welcome! It sounds like you might be better served using the SUMIF() function rather than copying values to new columns and summing the new columns. So, for example, `SUMIF(E1:E50, "=1", C1:C50)` would give you the sum for Marketing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need separate formulas in each of the cells M1 and N1.  A simple IF will do it.

M1:

```
=IF(E1=1,C1,"")
```

N1:

```
=IF(E1=2,C1,"")
```